# Count documents in Workspace / Library

Tags: contentworkspace

ContentWorkspaceDoc

```
SELECT COUNT(ContentWorkspaceId) FROM ContentWorkspaceDoc group by ContentWorkspaceId
```

> Error: "Grouped field should be aggregated: ContentWorkspaceId"

Is there any efficient way to check the count of documents in each library without querying for their counts individually?

As there are limits: 2000 libraries, or 50,000 documents per library ***one would assume*** it'd be possible to check these to maintain a large cache of documents!

*Additionally is it possible to create new `ContentWorkspace` records from APEX?*

```
insert new ContentWorkspace(Name='Whatever');
```

> Field is not writeable: ContentWorkspace.Name

Comment: "is it possible to create new ContentWorkspace records from APEX?" - nope - they can't be mocked with apex dml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:**

Your query should read:

```
SELECT contentworkspace.name, COUNT(ID) FROM ContentWorkspaceDoc group by contentworkspace.name
```

When I ran it in my environment, I get counts of ContentWorkspaceDocs per library

**Question 2 is it possible to create new ContentWorkspace records from APEX?**

Nope - they can't be mocked in testmethods either with apex dml. Even worse, they can't be created in the API as per the [Sobject doc on ContentWorkspace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspace.htm)

Comment: As of 40.0, you can create, update, or delete a library via the API.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspace.htm

Comment: @ministe2003 - cool -thanks for the update